# How to trigger the animation on model change in Angular.js

Tags: angularjs, animation

so I have a jade snippet like this

```
.statusbox 
    h5 {{status}}
```

which is equivalent to

```
<h5 class = "statusbox"> {{status}} </h5>
```

two questions:

1. one: Which ng directive we can use to trigger animation occur we defined in css file
2. What naming convention should b used for css class.

Thanks so much!

Leon

Answer (score 1):

ng-class will work just fine, assuming you're using CSS3 animations.

```
<h5 class="statusbox"  ng-class="{ 'animate-class' : foo }">{{status}}</h5>
```

Then whenever you set `$scope.foo = true` it will add the class `animate-class` to your `h5`. If your CSS3 animations are setup properly, it should animate.

Comment: This actually solved my another problem :D:
What if I want to catch the event whenever {{status}} changes?

Comment: @LeonJustCurious, best practice would be to check status whenever it might change, so that depends on *how* status is changing. If it's changing via user input, then ngChange would be apropos. If it's changing due to an AJAX call, you'd want to check it in your success callback. Some people would tell you to use $watch, but that's not really what $watch should be used for. You *can*, but it's sort of a lazy and inefficient hack.

Comment: it is change based on socket.io event....by checking ( without using $watch ) how am I suppose to trigger the animation event? also, what will be the naming convention for the animation class? animation-enter/leave?

Comment: well to trigger the animation event, you'd simply update `$scope.foo` to something "truthy", which will add `animate-class` to your `<h5>`. Adding `animate-class` should trigger the animation, assuming you've set up a CSS transition or keyframe animation on the h5 to begin with, and `animate-class` alters the property you're transitioning (or keyframing).

Comment: It should be noted that this would work in Angular 1.0.X as well.